# Are there any methods to get database metrics in spring?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot

I have a simple CRUD application that works with PostgreSQL database.

So I would like to know, are there any methods for collecting database metrics such as:
Date of first added entity, date of last added entity, amount of entities with specific value, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add this business logic as a service and create the RESTful interface to deliver the data, just as you would any other business use case.

When I read things like "amount of entities with specific value" - this is a query.

You can create these simply queries using Spring Data JPA methods.

Something like:

findByFieldEquals(String value);

[Here are the JPA keywords you can craft queries with](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)